# A* implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, path-finding, a-star

I'm trying to implement A* algorithm and I'm following the pseudocode from wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode
I'm stuck at this part
***tentative_gScore := gScore[current] + d(current, neighbor)***
what exactly is the d() function supposed to do?
`d(current,neighbor) is the weight of the edge from current to neighbor` but I don't get what they mean by that. In my case current and neighbor would be states(I'm building a snake game which is playing on its own) of the head of the snake. So lets say current is 15 and neighbor is 25, so d(15, 25) what should the function return?

Comment: It is just the distance from the current node to the next.

Comment: All edges have weights. The purpose of A* is to find a path between two (potentially distant) nodes so that the sum of all edge weights on the path is the lowest possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d is the distance to the next vertex in your graph. If you are on a regular square grid, it’s always 1.